# Multiple instances of modal

Tags: jquery, multiple-instances

I've constructed my own modal window script that takes precedence over the web browsers scroll bar and allows content to fill the page with an undefined height. It was hard to find any such script commercially available that had this specific property but I've got it to the stage that I am now satisfied with. The only problem is that I wish to have multiple instances of the modal window on one web page containing different content, and being slightly new to jQuery coding I am unsure of how to do this. My code is :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var body = $('body'),
        main = $('.main'),
        open_modal = $('.open-modal'),
        close_modal = $('.close-modal'),
        modal_container = $('.modal-container'),
        toggleModal = function() {
            body.toggleClass('body-locked') ;
            modal_container.toggleClass('dp-block');
        };

    $(".open-modal").click(function(){
        $(".modal-container").fadeIn(750);
    });

    open_modal.on('click', toggleModal);
    close_modal.on('click', toggleModal);
});
```

Comment: How can you have multiple modals? A modal is supposed to be on top of everything, that's it's point.

Comment: Sorry maybe I haven't worded that correctly. I'm creating a portfolio site and I've constructed the modal window as something that will carry detailed information about each individual project. I don't want multiple modals open at the same time but I want to be able to open a window with different content individually for each project.